# Why does my decryption function for the Caesar cipher produce faulty outputs?

Tags: c

I am currently working on a decryption function for a Caesar cipher. I have modelled this on the encryption function I had written, which works perfectly, unlike the decryption function.

My code compiles without any errors and executes. It is able to decrypt with words five letters or less, but is unable to do so with more than five letters and also with sentences containing two or more words.

Also it produces a faulty output for text when the value of the key is  <=12. Why do these errors occur?. Any form of help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/
}
```

Comment: Note: the `s` in the format `scanf("%99[^\n]s", text);` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the modulo operator does not always return a positive value:
`-1 % 26` gives `-1`, which makes your `decrypt_ltr` function return a character outside the `'a'`-`'z'` range (or `'A'`-`'Z'` range). For example, when decrypting '`a`' with a key of 2, you will get: `'a' - 'a' - key` = `-key`. You will then do `-key + 'a'`, which is still less than `'a'`.

Since your key is guaranteed to be between 1 and 26, you can simply add 26 to the `(alpha-'A') - key` value, like this:

```c
char decrypt_ltr(char alpha, int key) 
{
  if (alpha >= 'A' && alpha <= 'Z')
  {
      alpha = ((alpha-'A') - key + 26) % 26 + 'A'; // the 26 ensures that the value
                                                   // is positive before the modulo
                                                   // operator is applied and is
                                                   // removed by the modulo operator
  }
  else if(alpha >= 'a' && alpha <= 'z')
  {
      alpha = ((alpha-'a') - key + 26) % 26 + 'a';
  }

  return alpha;
}
```

Comment: @aw007 Don't forget to accept the answer, so that other people know it works.